# How to make Reactstrap's ListGroup unstyled?

Tags: reactstrap

I want to remove the boxes around the `<ListGroupItems>` in Reactstrap's `<ListGroup>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use Bootstrap's `border-0` class under [Borders Utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/borders/#subtractive).

```
<ListGroup>
  <ListGroupItem className="border-0">Item 1</ListGroupItem>
  <ListGroupItem className="border-0">Item 2</ListGroupItem>
</ListGroup>
```